# MySQL Conditional Sort

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Let's say I have following data in my `users` table.

```
name  | score
John  | 2
Dave  | 8
Joe   | -3
Sally | -20
Rose  | 0
```

How can I sort the users in following format by score column?

`John, Dave, Rose, Sally and Joe`

In other words those users that have positive scores should come first ascending, then 0 and then negative scores ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this uses the [`sign()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_sign) function:

```
order by sign(score) desc, score asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select * from mytable order by (score < 0), (score = 0), score
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd648c7ae33d2801f14a142b0266f890)**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps splitting it into 3 queries and combining the result?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE score > 0
    ORDER BY score DESC 
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE score = 0
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE score < 0
    ORDER BY score ASC 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT
name,
score,
(CASE WHEN score > 0 THEN 1 WHEN score < 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END ) as group
FROM 
ORDER BY group DESC, name DESC

this should work
the example you provided didn't match with the statement provided so you can change the order from DESC to AESC accordingly